# clang-3.9 doesn't link with poco libs compiled with abi::cxx11

Tags: c++, clang++, poco-libraries, libstdc++

I am on Fedora and trying to compile and link a project with Poco libraries installed on my system. Everything works fine with I compile and link my project with GCC 6. However, there's a linking error when I use `clang-3.9` to compile and link my project:

```
 undefined reference to `Poco::JSON::Object::operator Poco::Dynamic::Struct<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&() const'
```

I checked the symbols in `libPocoJSON.so` and it contains this:

```
0000000000022d80 T Poco::JSON::Object::operator Poco::Dynamic::Struct<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&[abi:cxx11]() const
```

So, the problem is that when I'm compiling with `clang`, it's looking for a symbol which doesn't exist in library.

I tried supplying `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1` to my program hoping that it will force it to look for symbols with the `abi:cxx11` tag but it doesn't help. I am confused now, whether this is a POCO issue, or `clang++` issue?

Edit:
Output of `clang -v`

```
clang version 3.9.1 (tags/RELEASE_391/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.4.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.4.1
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.4.1
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

Edit2:
Compile and link commands:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link clang++  -DTDOC=\"../test/data\" -I../common -I../net -I../wsd -I../kit -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 -std=c++11 -pthread -module -rpath /dummy -lz  -o test test-TileQueueTests.o test-WhiteBoxTests.o test-DeltaTests.o ../common/test-FileUtil.o ../common/test-SigUtil.o ../common/test-IoUtil.o ../common/test-Log.o ../common/test-Protocol.o ../common/test-Session.o ../common/test-Util.o ../common/test-MessageQueue.o ../kit/test-Kit.o ../wsd/test-Auth.o ../wsd/test-TileCache.o ../wsd/test-TestStubs.o ../common/test-Unit.o ../net/test-Socket.o test-TileCacheTests.o test-integration-http-server.o test-httpwstest.o test-httpcrashtest.o test-httpwserror.o test-test.o -lcppunit -lcap -lpng -ldl  -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil -lPocoJSON -lPocoFoundation -lPocoXML -lPocoNetSSL -lPocoCrypto -lpcre

libtool: link: clang++ -DTDOC=\"../test/data\" -I../common -I../net -I../wsd -I../kit -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 -std=c++11 -pthread -o test test-TileQueueTests.o test-WhiteBoxTests.o test-DeltaTests.o ../common/test-FileUtil.o ../common/test-SigUtil.o ../common/test-IoUtil.o ../common/test-Log.o ../common/test-Protocol.o ../common/test-Session.o ../common/test-Util.o ../common/test-MessageQueue.o ../kit/test-Kit.o ../wsd/test-Auth.o ../wsd/test-TileCache.o ../wsd/test-TestStubs.o ../common/test-Unit.o ../net/test-Socket.o test-TileCacheTests.o test-integration-http-server.o test-httpwstest.o test-httpcrashtest.o test-httpwserror.o test-test.o  -lz -lcppunit -lcap -lpng -ldl -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil -lPocoJSON -lPocoFoundation -lPocoXML -lPocoNetSSL -lPocoCrypto -lpcre -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/dummy
```

Edit3:
Linker Invcation:

```
 "/usr/bin/ld" --hash-style=gnu --no-add-needed --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o test /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.4.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.4.1/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.4.1/crtbegin.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.4.1 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.4.1/../../../../lib64 -L/usr/bin/../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.4.1/../../.. -L/usr/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib test-TileQueueTests.o test-WhiteBoxTests.o test-DeltaTests.o ../common/test-FileUtil.o ../common/test-SigUtil.o ../common/test-IoUtil.o ../common/test-Log.o ../common/test-Protocol.o ../common/test-Session.o ../common/test-Util.o ../common/test-MessageQueue.o ../kit/test-Kit.o ../wsd/test-Auth.o ../wsd/test-TileCache.o ../wsd/test-TestStubs.o ../common/test-Unit.o ../net/test-Socket.o test-TileCacheTests.o test-integration-http-server.o test-httpwstest.o test-httpcrashtest.o test-httpwserror.o test-test.o -lz -lcppunit -lcap -lpng -ldl -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil -lPocoJSON -lPocoFoundation -lPocoXML -lPocoNetSSL -lPocoCrypto -lpcre -rpath /dummy -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lpthread -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.4.1/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.4.1/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
```

Comment: Don't remember the details, but there was an ABI issue with old Clang versions and libstdc++. Can you upgrade to a recent Clang version?

Comment: @NikosC.Yes, that was approx 2 years ago. I am using clang-3.9 which is already quite new, I think.

Comment: maybe you could provide us with some info about the actual compile and link commands that are emitted? Also, having a look at what `clang -v` finds as candidate  `gcc` installations?

Comment: what about the compile and link lines? Although I don't have your configuration, I have the "feeling" that `clang` tries to link against a `libstdc++` that does not have the same ABI. See the troubleshooting section [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/using_dual_abi.html)

Comment: sorry for now clarifying, but I meant the actual linker invocation option, as you would get it with the `-v` option.

Comment: @compor updated

Comment: ok, I see the `-lstdc++` flag, but can you check that the `libstdc++` found in those dirs listed has the `__cxx11` namespace symbols (e.g. `std::__cxx11::basic_string`)?

Comment: @compor yes, it does. `nm -DC libstdc++.so.6 | grep -w std::__cxx11::basic_string` gives me tons of output